# add url access date to bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, koma-script

I'd like to add a single line to my bibliography

> url ressources last accessed on 2012-12-06

right between the head line (bibliography) and the first reference in the list.

I'm using simple BibTeX:

```
\documentclass[bibtotoc]{scrreprt}
...
\begin{document}
    ...
    \bibliographystyle{alpha}
    \bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

I'd prefer writing one last-accessed line rather than adding 10-15 last-accessed notes to all my online ressources.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

KOMA-Script provides `\AfterBibliographyPreamble` that can be used for this purpose:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\AfterBibliographyPreamble{URL ressources last accessed on 2012-12-06.}  
\begin{document}
\cite{Knuth:ct-a}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{texbook1}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]